# Django: What kind of querysets should i look for when deciding on model indexes?

Tags: python, mysql, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

In general, is there a type of Model query you look for to optimize by [indexing a field](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index) (`db_index=True`)?

In case it's relevant: I'm using MySQL.

### Elaboration:

Although I appreciate the responses already given. I was more looking for advice such as this one from a colleague:

> You should definitely index the fields in your default ordering and any field you use for filtering.

Think that about covers it?

Comment: Fields that get selected on, or joined on, that aren't already primary keys for those tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar)
2. Look at the SQL panel, look for long-running queries
3. Index the columns selected in those queries
4. If you need help with the queries, try the "EXPLAIN" MySQL command on the query.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should index fields that are searched for often. For example if you have a user-table then username could be indexed as well if things are constantly queried based on username. There are trade offs of course.